# Cron Job To Copy Changed or New Files or Folders

Tags: linux, rsync, cron

New here so please forgive me if this question (or a variation) has been asked and answered!

I am a linux newbie. I have a folder with multiple sub-folders and files on disk 1 and have done an initial copy to disk 2. I now want to create a daily cron job, which will keep disk 1 and disk 2 in sync (with disk 1 being considered the "master").

rsync seems to be the right tool but I am a little confused as to which options I need.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Think I have answered my own question! The advice here, [Which flags to use on rsync to achieve full replication?](https://superuser.com/questions/1601965/which-flags-to-use-on-rsync-to-achieve-full-replication), does the trick nicely.